# Reset animated gif on pageload

Tags: javascript, css

Below is html/css and javascript code I have that on page load should force the animated gif to reload/play on each page load.  The gif is being called in an external stylesheet via the class .content.  I'm wondering what I have missed as it's not working properly...

```js
var img = this.find('.content');
img.src = "../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif"+"?a="+Math.random();
```

```css
#banner a#main .content {
  background-image:url('../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif');
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: There are a few issues with the code you have posted. (1) You cannot set the `src` attribute directly on a jQuery object (seems like you are using jQuery from `this.find()`. (2) Setting the `src` is for `<img>` tags, not for background images of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all `img.src` won't do anything as you're trying to change the source of the *CSS attribute* "background-image" of a div, not the *HTML src attribute* of an img element.

You can change this CSS style in JavaScript in either of these ways:

jQuery:

`$(img).css("background-image","url('../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif"+"?a="+Math.random()+"')");`

Vanilla JavaScript:

`img.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/rt2/728x90_Animated_bg_2x.gif"+"?a="+Math.random()+"')";`

I have not tested this but it should do the trick. At least the jQuery version.